# Cancel Media Synchronization

Tags: admin, ce-1.7.0.2, media

Once started, is there any way to cancel the Media Synchronization?

I have a very large collection of files in the database and have again run out of disk space; Magento will happily continue creating 0kb files in the media folder until it has finished.

Comment: Is there such a thing as Media Synchronization built in Magento that I'm not aware of?  (other than the media/get.php file) O_o

Comment: Via admin: System > Configuration > System > Storage Configuration for Media

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to interrupt the synchronization process without killing the PHP process.

Depending on your OS and web server, you can find PHP processes with a command like

```
ps u -C php
```

then figure out which process it is based on the `START` time and call

```
kill 123
```

with 123 being the `PID`  of the process found in the previous output.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just restarted the apache server.

I'm not sure what options there would be for people on a shared server.